# Конвертировать Expression в sql c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, expressions

Например есть код

```
_users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Role == "Admin" && user.Id < 10)
```

Тут _users - DbSet. Можно ли конвертировать `user => user.Role == "Admin" && user.Id < 10` в текст SQL? Должно получится что-то `WHERE Role = 'Admin' AND Id <10`

Нужно написать Функцию вроде такой:

```
string ConvertExpToSql(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exp)
```

Которая возвращала бы SQL запрос полученного выражения.

Comment: Проще всего использовать свойство [Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log(v=vs.113).aspx). Для получения полной информации использовать [IDbCommandInterceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в вопросе DbSet используется как пример. У меня есть функция, которая принимает `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exp`, внутри нужно конвертировать параметр `exp` в SQL строку.

Comment: Я не знаю общедоступных конвертеров, не являющихся частью какой-нибудь ORM.

Comment: А зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: @PavelMayorov мне нужно сделать функцию, которая будет производить поиск в таблице базы данных по выражению. ORM для целевой платформы стоят денег, так что я пишу свой репозиторий. Я реализовал все функции, что мне нужны(Add, Remove, Update), осталось только Search реализовать.

Comment: @mirypoko: Они стоят денег именно потому, что написать такую функцию _сложно_.

Comment: @mirypoko можете порыться в поисках вдохновения тут: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6

Comment: Compact Framework вроде вообще не умеет в Expression Trees.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, вы правы, я и забыл что тестил свое приложение на полноценном фреймворке, так что придется что-то другое придумать. Но мой вопрос, как мне кажется, все равно актуален.